# Problema al mostrar el resultado de un select (round(AVG))

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

el problema que tengo es que al cargar la media de este select , no me carga en el jquery. La función devuelve correctamente la media. Si quito lo de round... si que carga el valor en el label que tengo. Que puede pasar?.
Eso es lo que devuelve. Simplemente no muestra.

[{"round(AVG(valoracion_usuario),1)":"6.5"}]

```
$resultado = $dbh->prepare("SELECT round(AVG(valoracion_usuario),1) FROM media_valoracion_usuarios WHERE cod_serie='S1'");

 function cargarPuntuacionMedia(){
      $.ajax({
        url:"cargarPuntuacionMedia.php",
        type:"GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){
          $.each(data,function(i,datos){
            var contenido=datos.valoracion_usuario;
            $("#mediaPuntuaciones").text(contenido);
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: colócale un alias a tu función de agregación; por ejemplo `round(AVG(valoracion_usuario),1) AS Valor` y desde tu JQuery accede a ese alias

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funciona :)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando uses funciones de agregación, será mas conveniente agregarle un alias a la columna calculada para después obtener dicho valor por medio de ese *alias*

Quedando tu consulta de este modo

```
$resultado = $dbh->prepare("SELECT round(AVG(valoracion_usuario),1) AS Valor 
                            FROM media_valoracion_usuarios 
                            WHERE cod_serie='S1'");
```

Para que ahora accedas a dicho valor así

```
var contenido=datos.Valor;
```

Pues no obtienes el valor ya que invocas el nombre de la columna regular de tu tabla, pero si revisas ese no es el nombre de la columna calculada que tienes con AVG por eso es mejor usar el alias